# Does IdentityHashMap entertain collisions?

Tags: java, data-structures

As per the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) of `IdentityHashMap`, it says

> This class implements the `Map` interface with a hash table, using
>   reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys
>   (and values). In other words, in an `IdentityHashMap`, two keys k1 and
>   k2 are considered equal if and only if `(k1==k2)`. (In normal `Map`
>   implementations (like `HashMap`) two keys k1 and k2 are considered equal
>   if and only if `(k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2))`.)

As I understand, two different objects pointing to different memory locations can still have same hashcode hence `object1.equals(object2)` can return `true`.
But two different objects pointing to different memory locations can never return `true` for `object1 == object2`.

**Question 1** - when `IdentityHashMap` relies strictly on reference equality, does that mean collisions will never occur?

**Question 2** - debugging the following code shows me 6 buckets in all with key and value both stored in separate buckets. But this is not the case with `HashMap`, where the key and value are stored in the same bucket.

As it's name has a 'hash' word in it, so it must be hashing the keys, then why does it store the keys and values separately and how does it retrieve the value of a given key?

```
String A = "abc";
String B = "def";
String C = new String("abc");
Map<String, String> map1 = new IdentityHashMap<String, String>();
map1.put(A, "123");
map1.put(B, "345");
map1.put(C, "567");
```

Comment: There's a lot of confused thinking here. 1. All hashing systems have to entertain collisions. 2. Having the same hash code does not imply that equals() returns true. 3. The presence of 'hash' in the name of a class has nothing to do with storing keys and values separately, which arises from the presence of the word 'map' in its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collisions happen when two different items have the same hash code, so obviously `IdentityHashMap` must deal with collisions. The only difference is that the "regular" hash map uses `equals` which can be `true` for different objects, while `IdentityHashMap` uses `==` that can't be `true` for different object.

The reason the "regular" hash map has separate variables for keys and values is an implementation detail of the `IdentityHashMap`: its implementation uses [*linear probing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) to address collisions, and it also stores keys and values in the same table: the key is placed at `table[hash]`, while the value is placed at `table[hash+1]`. The regular `HashMap` defines an `Entry` class which combines the key with its value in the same object, and stores entries in buckets.

Comment: The word is "linear probing"...solves all my confusion. I was stuck in the world of Linkedlist chaining. :)

Answer (score 5):

`IdentityHashMap` doesn't use the `hashCode` of the keys, but their `System.identityHashCode`. Although collisions of such identity hash codes are possible if you have a huge memory, they will be very seldom. That of course doesn't prevent two keys to end up in the same bucket, since the number of buckets is typically much smaller than 2^32 - 1.

Comment: Thanks JB. But I still can't think of 2 keys ending up in the same bucket when it uses reference equality. Could you provide an example or some way to perform this?

Comment: @Arham It's not the objects that must be equal in order to map to the same hash bucket -- it's their identity hash codes that must be the same.

Comment: To be exact, their identity hash code must be the same, or lead to the same bucket index when the hashing algorithm of the map is applied.

Answer (score 3):

> when IdentityHashMap relies strictly on reference equality, does that mean collisions will never occur?

Collisions are almost as likely as if it didn't. System hashCodes are not unique and even if they were the collections are not 2^^32 in size so only the hashCode has to be cut down to a small number of bits.

> how does it retrieve the value of a given key?

I would read the code to find out.

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Object k = maskNull(key);
    Object[] tab = table;
    int len = tab.length;
    int i = hash(k, len);
    while (true) {
        Object item = tab[i];
        if (item == k)
            return (V) tab[i + 1];
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        i = nextKeyIndex(i, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. So, this means that the value is always stored in the index next to the key. I verified that when debugging on the IDE but why did the JDK developers not use the general design of storing key and value together in one bucket. Off course it uses something called System.identityHashCode so what? Because of this it ultimately leads to increase in the number of buckets and ultimately occupying more space than the general HashMap which brings in another question that what real world use case would need such a Map?

Comment: Actually IHM uses less memory and is more cache efficient as a result as the "bucket" is only two references (8 bytes) whereas Map.Entry will be 16 - 24 bytes long in a random location in memory.  I suspect the differences is in when the code was written i.e. version 1.4 for IHM and version 1.2 for HM.